# Proper way to define default values for function arguments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, phpstorm

Since years from when I first met JavaScript I always used default values for function arguments, like:

```
function addToCartCallback3(responseData, toCartBtn = null) {
    // ...
}
```

But I noticed that now my PhpStorm warns me that this is wrong, and after 
`toCartBtn` comma `,` or closing parenthesis `)` is expected.

The code above works fine in Chrome and Firefox but kills all the JavaScript in IE11. *(In IE11 the console tells me the same as PhpStorm)*

Why is this code wrong, or what should I use?

I know that `(typeof toCartBtn == 'undefined')` should do the trick, but I'm really curious why is the other method all of a sudden considered syntactically wrong.

Answer (score 18):

As written this only works in ES6 browsers, since ES6 will contain this syntax for defaults.
So on IE11 you'll have to put the default inside the body:

```
function addToCartCallback3(responseData, toCartBtn) {
  toCartBtn = toCartBtn || 'defaultHere';
}
```

Do note that if you're default is supposed to be null, you can just not use a default, since in most cases, an undefined argument will behave the same way as a argument with value null.

Comment: This is used all over the place, but it's not overly safe. You mentioned NULL as being one problem, but it's any falsey value that you pass in that will cause problems - null, NaN, 0 (zero), "" (empty string), false itself - in addition to undefined which is what you want. Much better is the slightly longer but safer:

    `var = (var === undefined ? 'default' : var);`

Comment: That's very true. As written, any false-y value will go to the default, not only undefined. The question is about the syntax and IE11 though, not about properly handling false-y values, so I didn't think it was relevant to go into further detail. Especially since there aren't any false-y values that are valid buttons.

Comment: @PeterBowers 's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42768964/proper-way-to-define-default-values-for-function-arguments-in-javascript#comment99510814_42769077) works perfectly for boolean and string defaults in ES5 (default params were introduced in ES6)

See it in action at [playcode.io](https://playcode.io/726172/)

Answer (score 8):

IE11 does not support default parameters. This is an extension in ES6 in the JavaScript language that browser does not recognize.

You can see this by having a look at [this useful resource](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).  If you look at 'default function parameters' you will see it is not supported in that version of IE.

Comment: MDN also has a useful [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

Answer (score 3):

To get this syntax accepted by PHPStorm, please make sure to set **JavaScript language Version** to `ECMAScript 6` in `File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript`